# Making Text Field Disabled attribute dynamic with JSTL

Tags: html, jstl

I have a struts input text field, and I want the disabled attribute to change based on a dynamic value.
This is not working:

```
<html:text property="startDate" maxlength="14" disabled='<c:out value="${bbsInfoModel.waitMode}"/>' />
```

When I just use the c:out... on the page, the value is displayed:

```
Test Value: <c:out value="${bbsInfoModel.waitMode}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot embed a custom tag in another custom tag. Try this:-

```
<html:text property="startDate" maxlength="14" disabled="${bbsInfoModel.waitMode}" />
```

Comment: Used your idea but had to use <input> basic text field, not the struts version.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a HTML-el tag for this:

```
<html-el:text .......... disabled="${bbsInfoModel.waitMode}">
```

so instead of html-text, put html-el:text.

This is what I had to do to make mine work.