# making struts 1.0 textbox readonly

Tags: java, html, css, struts

its really odd to find that when i start the server, the disabled attribute doesn't appear in my browser page.

```html
<td class="label" width="20%"><bean:message key="mrBeanName" /></td>
        <td width="30%"><td width="30%"><html:text property="mrbeanId" size="30" maxlength="16" disabled="disabled"/></td></td>
```

is there something i am missing, or is this the case for Struts 1.0?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making Text Field Disabled attribute dynamic with JSTL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121909/making-text-field-disabled-attribute-dynamic-with-jstl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the [API](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/html/text.html), it should be `readonly="true"` or `disabled="true"`.